# eclipsing a global variable name by a static member name

Tags: c++

If one includes windows.h in a c++ file in Visual Studio, they then have a global identifier named STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL defined.  I would like to use that name as a name for a static member variable in a class I am creating.  I attempted to do it as follows...

```
class ACLAmigo
{
public:
    static int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL;
    ACLAmigo(void);
    ~ACLAmigo(void);
};
```

Later on in another file I have this...

```
int ACLAmigo::STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 1;
```

But the IDE complains thusly: "Error: expected an identifier".

Question:  Can I use this already declared identifier STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL as a member variable name and if so how?

Comment: STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL is probably a macro.  You could #undef it, but you may be asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks in fact it is a "#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL (0x001F0000L)".  I actually can't undef it because I then want to set my variable to this value using the macro name (a #define is a macro right?).  If I add an underscore in front of my variable name it works.  I will live with that if I must but it would be nice not to have to.

Comment: I've added an answer that deals with that problem.

Comment: It is customary to have macros be all caps to set them apart from regular variables. This all come to waste if you use all caps for regular variables, of course, so I would advise against doing that: this way you will avoid clashes. `StandardRightsAll` or `standar_rights_all` would work as well, would not they ?

Comment: Yes, thanks those names would work just fine.  I wanted consistency between the name in windows.h and the name I used but now I see that was an impossible dream.  Learning while doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL` (and most of the other things) is the **macro**. Macros are always "globally defined". Moreover, they're resolved by the preprocessor before the compiler starts to analyze your code so that your code turns into:

```
static int 0x001F0000 /*STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL*/;
```

which is a nonsense.

Either pick another variable name, or undefine that macro:

```
#undef STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL
static int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL; // now it's ok
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm changing the name of my variable.  Branching question:  Is it considered a standard/best practice to give constant static class members names with all caps?

Comment: Depends on the convention. I personally don't so this. I do stick to the convention where static members come with `s_` prefix

Answer (score 1):

Well, since `STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL` is actually a macro:

```
#define STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL              (0x001F0000L)
```

I'd say there's no *safe* way of doing it.

You could undefine it:

```
#undef STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL
class ACLAmigo
{
public:
    static int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL;
    ACLAmigo(void);
    ~ACLAmigo(void);
};
```

but you're much better off if you just choose a different name.

**In fact, it's undefined behavior to undefine standard macros.** This isn't a standard macro, but could also lead to undefined behavior. You should definitely change the name.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm changing the name of my variable.  Branching question:  Is it considered a standard/best practice to give constant static class members names with all caps?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you set it to 1, but I'm thinking you actually want to set it to the value that the STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL macro normally has.

I think you could accomplish that like this:

```
class ACLAmigo
{
public:
    static const int standard_rights_all = STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL;
#undef STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL
    static const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = standard_rights_all;
    ACLAmigo(void);
    ~ACLAmigo(void);
};
```

but this could easily lead to problems if this occurs in a header file that gets included before other header files that use the macro.